# How many square units are in the area of the triangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

So i'm trying to solve this problem without counting the square units in the triangle. So i thought of finding the lengths of RS and ST and find the area of the quadrilateral but since we have a triangle, I would divide by 2.

I found RS to be 6 units and ST to be 12 units, which means the area of the quadrilateral would be 72 units squared and half is 36 units squared. However, that is not a choice and it turns out the right answer is 45 but i can't seem to figure out how they got that answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: good idea, and the method is correct since $RS$ and $ST$ are perpendicular.  But your length calculations for $RS$ and $ST$ are wrong.

Comment: Alright, So I think I see what I did wrong. I recalculated using the distance formula and got RS to be $\sqrt(45)$ and ST to be $\sqrt(160)$ but then I got the area to be 42.42

Comment: Try $ST$ again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach: The triangle $RST$ is bounded by a square whose sides have length $12$ and are parallel to the axes. So the triangle can be seen as a square minus three triangles, with corresponding area
$$
12^2 - \frac12(3\cdot 6 + 6\cdot 12 + 9\cdot 12) = 45.
$$

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you arrived at $RS=6$ and $ST=12$, but they are incorrect.  The distance formula is $$\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$ to find the distance between any two points $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$.  So, $$RS = \sqrt{(-2+5)^2+(7-1)^2} = \sqrt{45}$$ and $$ST = \sqrt{(7+5)^2+(-5-1)^2} = \sqrt{180}$$  Plugging these numbers into the area formula, we get $$A = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{180} \cdot \sqrt{45} = \frac{90}{2} = 45$$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.